# I want to run electric from a 100A RV pedestal to a shed which is 6' from the RV pedestal

Tags: shed

How do I access the RV pedestal with the 14ga wire that I plan to put thru PVC  conduit?
The pedestal is a metal box from Home Depot and buried about 2 fit into the ground. Can I run line thru a drilled hole in the metal box or do I need to bring the new wire up from the bottom of the metal pedestal?

Comment: How about a picture of what you've got.  Why are you running #14 AWG? That's awful small.

Comment: A *typical* RV pedestal has a 50A 240V circuit, a 30A 120V circuit and a 20A 120V. Some have an additional space or two, to which you could add another circuit and extend it to the shed. If they don't have that extra space then your only real option is to extend the 20A circuit off the load terminals of the GFCI with **12** AWG wire. But this is all guesswork without more details and, ideally, a picture.

Comment: Can you post photos of your particular RV pedestal, including any labeling on it?